# PHP GD: merge a blurry rectangle

Tags: php, gd

I need to merge a blurry rectangle on another image (a white rectangle). I tried to `imagesavealpha()` but unfortunately the background of the rectangle remains black, and I want it with a gradient from red to white.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$width = 200;
$height = 180;

$bw = $bh = 30;

$img1 = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$img2 = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

$white = imagecolorallocate($img1, 255, 255, 255);
$red = imagecolorallocate($img2, 255, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($img1, 0, 0, 100, 100, $white);
imagefilledrectangle($img2, 5, 5, 25, 25, $red);

imagefilter($img2, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
imagefilter($img2, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
imagefilter($img2, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
imagefilter($img2, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
imagefilter($img2, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);

imagesavealpha($img2, true);

imagecopymerge($img1, $img2, 20, 20, 0, 0, $bw, $bh, 100);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($img1);

imagedestroy($img1);
```

The restulting image is:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you just want a blurred red rectangle on a white background your code can be simplified to this:

```
<?php
$width = 200;
$height = 180;

$img = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

// fill with opaque white.
imagefill($img, 0, 0, 0x00ffffff);

// draw rectangle in opaque red.
imagefilledrectangle($img, 5, 5, 25, 25, 0x00ff00000);

for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR);
}

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

Result (of course the white background blends with the page background...):

[image: result]

If you want to be able to blend the red rectangle with any background colour (full alpha blending) then you might be out of luck.  As far as I can tell `IMG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR` doesn't support alpha values (I'm using PHP 7.0.3).

Comment: Actually my real background is not just white, it is a pattern. But `MG_FILTER_GAUSSIAN_BLUR` not supporting alpha values answers my question. Do you know an alternative to get a similar or approaching result?

Comment: Not in GD. I tried the [example for `imageconvolution`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageconvolution.php#example-3501) but got exactly the same result as `imagefilter`. [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.gaussianblurimage.php) is probably your best bet, but isn't always available.